# Let $h:X\to Y$ a morphism of varieties. It is generally true that $h(X)$ is a subvariety of $Y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am a little confused with this, my intuition tells me that this is not true but I don't know what counterexample I should take, could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Say $X,Y$ are affine varieties, the kernel of $h^* : k[Y] \to k(X),h^*( f(Y))=f(h(X))$ is a prime ideal $I$ and $h(X)$ is dense in the subvariety $V(I)$ of $Y$. Taking $X= V(x_1x_2-1), Y = \Bbb{A}^1,h(x_1,x_2) = x_1$ shows $h(X)$ doesn't have to be closed, but its closure is a subvariety.

Comment: There are **so** many different definitions of variety. You really need to include yours if you hope to get a sensible answer. This is definitely not true for affine varieties (project $xy-1 = 0$ on the $x$-axis), but is true for projective varieties.

Comment: @André3000 
My definition of variety is an irreducible algebraic set.

Comment: I suggest reading about Chevalley's theorem, which says that $h(X)$ is constructible and that is the best you can do in general.

Comment: @reuns $h(X)=k-\{(0,0)\}$  why is it not closed in the zariski topology?

Answer (score 3):

You might find this wikipedia article useful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology)

It gives a counterexample to your question $A^2 \to A^2$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$ but also explains an alternative to your question.